# function expansion perpendicular to plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

In thermodynamics, you sometimes want to calculate (a part of) the volume of the $6N$-dimensional phase space, where $N$ is the particle number. I'm trying to understand where the equation for that volume comes from (the equation itself is not relevant here). In a textbook, I read that one has to "expand the Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ perpendicular to the equienergy planes" where the equienergy planes are given by $H(q,p) = E = const.$

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to actually write down the necessary Taylor expansion. I hope this is enough information for you to show me how to do this.